# React Native: how do you trigger an event when you swipe back to a screen that's already mounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my React Native app, I have an event that I want to be triggered whenever a certain screen appears. I put the event in `componentDidMount`, so it triggers when the screen first loads, but if I navigate away from the screen and the left swiped to return to the screen, the screen's already mounted so the event isn't triggered.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `react-navigation` you can do this in `componentDidMount` to trigger event on already mounted screen.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const {navigation} = this.props;
    this.onFocusTrigger = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // trigger your event
    });
  }
```

In addition to `'focus'`, you can use following as well depending on your need.

- `willFocus`
- `didFocus`
- `didBlur`
- `willBlur`

You need to unsubscribe listener in componentWillUnmount like this

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.onFocusTrigger();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your navigation framework. For example, if you're using React Navigation, you should check out [Navigation Events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/). (Make sure that you're on the right version of the docs for the version you're using.)